# Where is the default installation path of c#.net after you install it using setup?

Tags: c#, windows

[image]

After I clicked the setup.exe from the attached image, I do not know where the installed files located in my computer

I want to get it's path something like: C:\Program Files\MyApplication\app.exe

Comment: Like `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework` and related folders?

Comment: Or `C:\Program Files\dotnet`

Comment: no, I only want the installed applications files location

Comment: In fact your question is not about programming but about using some app, try SuperUser instead.

Comment: Your app might be ClickOnce, then the files are in an obfuscated folder.

Comment: Please [edit] the title to make it clear. Currently is asks for the default location of C#.NET which can be interpreted of  the location of the .NET (Framework) binaries.